# Web preview link Android

Tags: android

I'm developing a feature is web preview link on Android
but I facing problem with url: https://jp.mercari.com/

Im tried using jsoup to get all tag (https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-preview-for-a-link-in-android-6906d0aa9e12)

→ I can get all meta tag with site https://shop.adidas.jp/ but it doesn't work with https://jp.mercari.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDuAz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ZoN.png)

any idea is good for me. Thanks!!!

Expected: preview link works fine with url: https://jp.mercari.com/